# jQuery.ajax "data" parameter syntax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to pass the contents of a javascript variable to the server for processing.  I can pass static strings no problem but when I pass a variable containing a string, the WebMethod is not called.  Here is my code:
(Client)

```
function expand(checkbox) 
{
    var selectedrow = checkbox.parentNode.parentNode;
    var rowindex = selectedrow.rowIndex;
    var parent = document.getElementById("parentTable");
    var NextRow = parent.rows[rowindex + 1];

    var cols = selectedrow.cells[1];
    var ID = cols.firstElementChild.attributes.value;


    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "Playground.aspx/childBind",
        data: "{sendData: ID}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) { alert("successful!" + result.d); }
    })

    NextRow.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

(Server)

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string childBind(string sendData)
    {
        return String.Format("Hello");
    }
```

Now, if I were to try data: "{sendData: "ok"}", the WebMethod gets called and returns a response.  How is my syntax wrong?

Comment: Works here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262940/webmethod-not-being-called

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to pass it as a string. Since `ID` is a javascript variable you have to pass its value. When you pass data as `"{sendData: ID}"` it will not pass the value of `ID`.

Try this

```
data: { sendData: ID }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work although it did allow me to catch an error elsewhere. After a small modification in the javascript, I am now storing the correct value.

    var ID = cols.firstElementChild.defaultValue;

However, the server-side web method is still not being called.  I noticed if I comment out the "contentType" & "dataType" lines, the "success" statement on the client side is called.  "ID" holds a string value from a hiddenfield that is actually a GUID (but is a string when stored.)  The server-side webmethod expects a string.

Comment: What modification you did? You mean you are still passing ` data: "{sendData: ID}"` and it works?

Comment: no.  I fixed that AND var ID = cols.firstElementChild.defaultValue; Still doesn't work.

Comment: Did my solution helped you in any way? If yes, then I think you should mark this as an answer. If you have a different problem then you should create another question.

Comment: Well, no, the question still stands because it isn't working.  The server-side WebMethod isn't being called when passing a variable instead of a string literal.

Answer (score 3):

You were sending a string instead of an object (`"{sendData: ID}"` instead of `{sendData: ID}`). And the data you were sending wasn't JSON. So remove the contentType line and change the data line. You should re-write this as:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "Playground.aspx/childBind",
    data: {sendData: ID},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) { alert("successful!" + result.d); }
})
```

You can also write this, if you want to send JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "Playground.aspx/childBind",
    data: $.getJSON({sendData: ID}),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) { alert("successful!" + result.d); }
})
```

Comment: It seems like right data is in place now but the server-side web method is still not being called. I noticed if I comment out the "contentType" & "dataType" lines, the "success" statement on the client side is called. "ID" holds a string value from a hiddenfield that is actually a GUID (but is a string when stored.) The server-side webmethod expects a string.

Comment: You should remove the contentType line since you are not sending the data as json (you just receive data back as json) OR you can add jQuery.getJSON() around your data

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery run these tests for the answer:

```
var ID = 45;

var x = "{sendData: ID}";

alert(jQuery.isPlainObject(x));  // false

var y = { sendData: ID};

alert(jQuery.isPlainObject(y)); // true
```

Here is the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ugKE/

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in 'ID' as a **string** rather than a variable.
All you need to do is remove the quotes around your data object.

Further reading on JSON and javascript objects:

http://www.json.org/

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: It seems like right data is in place now but the server-side web method is still not being called. I noticed if I comment out the "contentType" & "dataType" lines, the "success" statement on the client side is called. "ID" holds a string value from a hiddenfield that is actually a GUID (but is a string when stored.) The server-side webmethod expects a string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "Playground.aspx/childBind",
        data: JSON.stringify({sendData: ID}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) { alert("successful!" + result.d); }
    })
```