# What is the mistake in this ajax webservice call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

This is my Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "http://localhost:63384/ListWebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
            success: function (data) { alert(data) }
        });
    });
```

and my webservice contains

```
[WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

While running asmx i am getting correct output.the same url produces output when i use post method. but the script produces nothing,not even empty alert box. what is the error?

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: No Nothing i am getting.

Comment: Same domain between your page and your service ?

Comment: yes when i use post method i am getting the output, i want to get the output by ajax now.

Comment: Referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262940/webmethod-not-being-called?rq=1 what about alert(data.d) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add contentType to your ajax call. And, as I remember. your result will be in data.d
For example:

```
dataType: 'json',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

**UPDATE**

Try to use aspx page with webmethod. It looks like your web.config is not tuned for asmx. Might be that GET is not allowed.

This works:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Default.aspx/HelloWorld",
                success: function (data) { alert(data.d); }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: added content type and datatype. now if i put data the alert box is coming with "null" as output. when i put data.d the alert box is not coming.

Comment: alert("success"+data.d);--->no alert box;  alert("success"+data)--->"Successnull" in alert box;alert("success")--->"success" in alert box;

Comment: And ensure your web.config handle mappings.

Comment: tried,it is not hitting. but even in post method it is not hitting. but i am getting corrct output in post method.

Comment: when the datatype is changed to "text" i am getting alert box "undefined".

Comment: Yes, and make your HelloWorld static, please )

Comment: [WebMethod]
        static public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }   still "undefined" alert box.

Comment: rit,i got the output in IE... As "Hello World" alert box comes in IE... But chrome is still not producing output.

Comment: url: "http://localhost:63384/ListWebService.asmx/HelloWorld"... this itself works fine... but chrome is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what goes wrong
Best way to get the intell is to add an error handler to your ajax call which you can debug.
It should/could look like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "http://localhost:63384/ListWebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
            success: function (data) { alert(data) }
            error: function (request, status, error) {
              alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Edit:

I'm guessing your webservice is not configured for get calls but only posts.
 You could dive in the config files to enable a get but maybe try and change the type parameter to post first to see if that works.

Comment: Now also it is blank. I am not even getting alert box inside error function.

Comment: If neither the success nor the error function is triggered then you will have received a javascript error. Maybe jquery is not loaded or something but an errorless jquery call will always return a success or an error callback.

Comment: Post method also produces nothing.

Comment: but the same script with url of another aspx page produces correct output. just webservice url is not working.

Comment: I aggree with westie, this behavior is not normal so assuming you're not lying you are probably missing something. Any other url would still result in either a success or an error.

Comment: I reproduced your error. It seams like your web.config not configured for asmx. Try to use aspx page with web method. This works:<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Default.aspx/HelloWorld",
                success: function (data) { alert(data.d); }
            });
        });
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
url: "Page.aspx/WriteWebMethodName"
```

Comment: i have tried url: "ListWebService.asmx/HelloWorld" still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a breakpoint on the return in the service does it get hit? If not then the url is probably wrong.