# How to call c# function from js function inside asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing my first website in vs using asp.net and c#.
How can I call c# function from js function inside asp.net? I want to insert form data into sql database.

**C# (add_project.aspx.cs):**

```
using System.Web.Services;
public partial class add_project : System.Web.UI.Page
{
[WebMethod]    
public static void InsertIntoDatabase(string projectname, string piname)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");// this doesn't appear which mean it doesn't enter this function
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=databasename;Integrated Security=SSPI");
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Projects (project_name, principal_investigator) VALUES (@project_name,@pi_name)";

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@project_name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@principal_investigator", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        param[0].Value = projectname;
            param[1].Value = piname;
            for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
            }

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

**js in the aspx file (add_project.aspx):**

```
<script>
  function doSomething() {

      var $projectname = $("#project_name").val();
      var $piname = $("#pi_name").val();
      alert($piname);    // This alert appear
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'add_project.aspx/InsertIntoDatabase',
          data: "{'projectname':'" + $projectname + "', 'piname':'" + $piname + "' }", //Pass the parameter names and values
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (msg) {
              alert('success');
          },
          error: function (e) {
              alert('error');       // this msg appear
          }
      });
         }
```

**form in the aspx file (add_project.aspx):**

```
    <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" id="add_project_form" runat="server" onsubmit="doSomething();">
    <div id="wizard" class="form_wizard wizard_horizontal">
<!-- Project Name -->
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="project_name">Project Name <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <asp:TextBox id="project_name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                          </div>
<!-- PI name -->
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="pi_name">PI Name <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <asp:TextBox id="pi_name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                          </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I don't have access to the submit button of the form (because I use bootstrap template) .

Thanks

**Solution:**
I solve the problem by put [WebMethod] before the c# function
Also, I were have error syntax in the insert statement.
Thanks @Pawan and all for the help.

Comment: remove `.cs` extension from `url`

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: you can use [WebMethod] attribute on your method to access it from client side

Comment: What specific error you are getting?

Comment: refere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262940/webmethod-not-being-called

Comment: @Pawan  the alert msg 'error' is displayed

Comment: Check the browser console for the error.https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors

Comment: @alaa Use `error: function(xhr, status, error) {
   alert(error)
}` to know about error details in your ajax call

Comment: @Pawan I got this: System.Exception: 'Insert Error:Must declare the scalar variable "@pi_name".'

Comment: @alaa so the error is in `c#` `InsertIntoDatabase` method

Comment: @alaa rename `@pi_name` to `@principal_investigator`

Comment: @Pawan oooooooh! it is working now. i rename it. But, i think it doesn't enter the c# function because i put Console.WriteLine("hello"); and it doesn't appeared !  thanks a lot

Comment: @alaa glad to help you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the c# method should be a webmethod .

```
[WebMethod]
```

here goes your c# method

you need to import `system.web.services` into your code first ,

```
using System.Web.Services;
```

and write the `js` function into the form submit event ( if you cant access submit button)

write `onsubmit="yourfun()"`  inline in the form

or if you are using jquery

```
$("#form-id").submit(function(){

    your function;

});
```

Comment: I already wrote <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" id="add_project_form" runat="server" onsubmit="doSomething();">

Comment: can you put a debugger in your c# code and check whether it hits the backend..?