# Bundle third party .exe in Python code and produce another portable .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I would like to use a few [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) (let say `seq.exe` in this example) in my Python code and then convert it to exe.

The code would be like this.

```
import os
os.system('seq 1 3')
```

If I copy `seq.exe` in the computer, the code will be executed just fine.

```
C:\>python test.py
1
2
3

C:\>
```

However, when I delete `seq.exe` from the PC, then I'll get the following error which expected as `seq.exe` is no longer there.

```
C:\>python test.py
'seq' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>
```

To solve this problem, I would like to bundle `seq.exe` with my Python program and produce another .exe with `seq.exe` inside it so it would be portable and can be used in any other computer even though `seq.exe` is not there.

Previously I was using `PyInstaller` to produce .exe. The only problem right now is I'm not sure how to combine the third party .exe with the python code and produce another portable .exe program.

Comment: You can refer my answer at below link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72640313/19115308

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebMethod not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262940/webmethod-not-being-called)