# How to bundle third party .exe in stanadlone Python executable

Tags: pyinstaller, nuitka

I'm writing scripts to automate some task to be executed from windows machine to remote ubuntu server, which uses putty-tools like plink.exe, pscp.exe and psftp.exe.

My python program is able to run successfully but I'm trying to build a single independent standalone file which can be run in another PC even if that PC do not have these putty tools available.

I'm using below commands

python -m nuitka --enable-plugin=tk-inter --windows-disable-console --onefile --standalone my_program.py

I'also found related question here but it was not answered
[Bundle third party .exe in Python code and produce another portable .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53500353/19115308)

Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: This way of bumping a question is not encouraged. Please ask a new question or improve the old one to attract answers. By improving the old one, it gets bumped too.

Comment: Hi Dugnom, I've updated my question, I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately I found answer for my question by reading the nuitka user manual, we need to use one of the below format based on the requirement. In my case I used second one.

```
# This will find a file near your onefile.exe
open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), "user-provided-file.txt"))
# This will find a file inside your onefile.exe
open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "user-provided-file.txt"))
```

And while packing my command become something like below,here it will include all the files available in source directory to target directory in "onefile.exe"

```
python -m nuitka --enable-plugin=tk-inter --windows-disable-console --onefile
--include-data-dir=<source>=<target> --standalone my_program.py
```