# Jquery Ajax POST Request sending data issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, post

I have searched a lot and not been able to find a working solution to why my post request is not sending it's data to the server. I can send the request without data and I get my results from the server, but I just cannot send my data to the server. I have narrowed it down to the "data" attribute and assume I am just doing something wrong. Thank you.

**Client**

```
var scriptURL = "default/scripts/serverside/Scripts.aspx";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseURL + scriptURL + "/SaveItem",
    data: "{}",                                           //works (to return a result)
    //data: "{sendData: '" + dataPackage + "'}",            //does not work
    //data: dataPackage,                                    //does not work
    //data: { sendData: dataPackage },                      //does not work
    //data: { "sendData": dataPackage },                    //does not work
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        de("server result:" +result);
    }
});
```

**Server**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveItem(string sendData)
{
    string result = "received: " + sendData;
    return result;
}
```

Please help, I just cant seem to get it working and know it has got to be a syntax issue...

Similar problems I have found (but no working answers):

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258933/jquery-ajax-data-parameter-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262940/webmethod-not-being-called?lq=1)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262940/webmethod-not-being-called?lq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258933/jquery-ajax-data-parameter-syntax)

Comment: Can you open up your browser's Javascript debugger and bring up a page with this edit:

    $.post('baseURL + scriptURL + "/SaveItem"', { sendData: 'foobar'} );

Comment: You should pass the data as a string. Jquery will serialize the string itself. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061884/asp-net-jquery-ajax-data-param-problem

Comment: @chrisHardie, ran it with "dataPackage" in quotes and checked the debugger, it simply says I am sending sendData=dataPackage as one large string...

Comment: @RMK, I just tried passing the whole things as a string and it didnt work...

Comment: Please don't add `[solved]` to your title or a summary of the answers to the question - the answers themselves serve the latter purpose and the checkmark serves the former. If you want add more detail past what the other answerers have given, please add your own answer with the details.

Comment: @janDvorak, Thanks for the tip. I assume you already removed it. However, what about the actual solution in the answer? I see you removed it as well. I put that there for a reason -so that there is completeness for anyone else who just wants the answer. Further, placing the 'solution' in the actual question container adds credibility that this 'solution' has been verified by the original asker....

Comment: @janDvorak, Lastly, I would have greatly preferred you actually implement all of the fixes you insist on instead of simply censoring my post. For instance, you deleted my solution instead of placing it in an answer like you suggested......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: baseURL + scriptURL + "/SaveItem",
   data: $.toJSON({ sendData: dataPackage }),                      
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (result) {
       de("server result:" +result);
   }
});
```

The `toJSON` will convert your JS object into a proper JSON string. You could also use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: This is the closest I've gotten, but now the data is being passed to the server (so says firebug) but I cannot get a response with the result. I assume, you cannot simply declare the JSON incoming object as a string...

Comment: additionally, I had to add ', ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]'

Comment: Cool! :) Glad you got it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var scriptURL = "default/scripts/serverside/Scripts.aspx";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseURL + scriptURL + "/SaveItem",
    data: {sendData: "string to send" }
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        de("server result:" +result);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work. However, even if I send anything it should still respond with what the server received, right?